# Maintaining a "variable" in regular expressions?

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there any way using regular expressions to match and replace with a "variable string" like...

```
foo_1_a => bar_1_b
foo_2_a => bar_2_b
foo_3_a => bar_3_b
```

...

Using some expression with a variable "var" for example

"replace `foo_var => [0-9]_a` with `bar_var_b` "

Specifically I'm trying to take in one regex/replacement from command line using Ruby and executing all these replacements. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use a part of the string in replacement? Like you replace `foo_1_a` with `bar_1_b` where `1` is come from string?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for back reference replace string. This is usually done by `\1` or `$1`. The number `1` is the previously matched group's order.

So match `foo_2_a` by `foo_(\d+)_a`. Here parenthesis creates a group. And its the first group. So replace it with `bar_\1_b`. `\1` will contain `2`

More about [Back Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here we go.

```
result = "foo_1_a".match(/_([0..1])_/){ "bar_#{$1}_b" }
puts result # "bar_1_b"
```